# How to replace a Value in a Dict from another Dict but based on a key value in the first Dict

Tags: python, dictionary

For say I have two dictionaries like so:

```
dict1 = {'project' : 'Administration', 'cost_center' : 'N/A'} 
        {'project' : 'Non-Work Time', 'cost_center' : 'N/A'}

dict2 = {'project':'Administration', 'cost_center': 'F99'}
        {'project':'Non-Work Time', 'cost_center': 'F88'}
```

I need help finding a way to replace 'N/A' with the value from dict2 cost_center. I think an IF statement would be best like: if it finds "N/A" then replace with the value that is in dict2 if it doesn't find that value keep it "N/A"

Example of desired output:

```
dict1 = {'project' : 'Administration', 'cost_center' : 'F99'}  
        {'project' : 'Non-Work Time', 'cost_center' : 'F88'}
```

Pseudo:

```
if dict1['cost_center'] == "N/A':
       Replace 'cost' if 'project' == exists in dict2
else:
       continue
```

Comment: If there's even the slightest possibility of cleaning up your data structures instead of doing all this post-processing, I would strongly recommend doing so.

Comment: Your data structure isn't any cleaner or easier to use, it's just been shuffled around a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension :

```
>>> dict1 = {'project' : 'Non-Work Time', 'cost' : 'N/A'}
>>> dict2 = {'Administration': 'F99' , 'Non-Work Time': 'Q99'}
>>> dict1 = {i:dict2[dict1['project']] if i=='cost' and j=='N/A' else j for i,j in dict1.items()}
>>> dict1
{'project': 'Non-Work Time', 'cost': 'Q99'}
```

But note that your dictionaries must contain the expected keys in otherwise it will raise a `KeyError`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and helpful response! @Kasramvd